# Converting an ArrayList into a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In Java how do you convert a ArrayList  into a two dimensional array Object[][]?

From comments:  I will describe you the problem with more details: an XML file includes a list of contacts (e.g. name, address...). The only way I can obtain this information is through an ArrayList, which will be given to me. As I need to store the content of this array list in a Java Swing table in an ordered manner, I was thinking to convert it into a two dimensional array of objects

Comment: an array list is 1D, I don't understand what your question means

Comment: perhaps the ArrayList contains a List of Object arrays...

Comment: I will describe you the problem with more details: an XML file includes a list of contacts (e.g. name, address...). The only way I can obtain this information is through an ArrayList<Contacts>, which will be given to me. As I need to store the content of this array list in a table in an ordered manner, I was thinking to convert it into a two dimensional array of objects...

Comment: what kind of table? database table? swing JTable? html table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find "a way" to do so, knowing the number of attributes each contacts has (6). So considering an `ArrayList listofContacts`

```
    int numberOfContacts = listofContacts.size()/6;
    Object[][] newArrayContent = new Object[numberOfContacts][6];

    for(int x = 0; x<numberOfContacts; x++){
        for(int z = 0; z < 6; z++){
        int y = 6 * x;
        newArrayContent [x][z] = list.get(y+z); 
        System.out.println(newArrayContent [x][z].toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I presume you are using the [`JTable(Object[][], Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) constructor.

Instead of converting an `ArrayList<Contact>` into an `Object[][]`, try using the [`JTable(TableModel)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29) constructor. You can write a custom class that implements the [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface. Sun has already provided the [`AbstractTableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) class for you to extend to make your life a little easier.

```
public class ContactTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Contact> contacts;

    public ContactTableModel(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        // return however many columns you want
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: return "Name";
        case 1: return "Age";
        case 2: return "Telephone";
        // ...
        }
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Contact contact = contacts.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0: return contact.getName();
        case 1: return contact.getAge();
        case 2: return contact.getTelephone();
        // ...
        }
    }

}
```

Later on...

```
List<Contact> contacts = ...;
TableModel tableModel = new ContactTableModel(contacts);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to add a method to the `Contact` like this:

```
public Object[] toObjectArray() {
    return new Object[] { getName(), getAddress, /* ... */ };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ArrayList<Contact> contacts = /* ... */
Object[][] table = new Object[contacts.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
    table[i] = contacts.get(i).toObjectArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(..);
list.add(..);
list.add(..);
list.add(..);
list.add(..);
list.add(..);
int[][] a = new int[list.size()][list.size()];
    for(int i =0; i < list.size(); i++){
      for(int j =0; j <list.size(); j++){
        a[i][j]= list.get(j +( list.size() * i));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to sort the ArrayList. To do that your Contacts class must implement a Comparator method.

Check the next page for an example: http://www.java-examples.com/sort-java-arraylist-descending-order-using-comparator-example

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you parse your XML into java objects and store the object in a custom data object. This will make it easier for you to do many operations on the available data.

[Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/) is small tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[][] convertListIntoArrayObj(List<TeamMenuSelected> possibilities) {
    int numberOfColums = 2;
    int numberOfRows = possibilities.size();
    String[][] values = new String[numberOfRows][numberOfColums];

    for(int x=0; x<possibilities.size(); x++) {
        TeamMenuSelected item = possibilities.get(x);
        values[x][0] = item.getTeamName();
        values[x][1] = item.getTeamCuisine();
    }

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("element_1");
    arrayList.add("element_2");
    arrayList.add("element_3");
    arrayList.add("element_4");
    int k=0;
    int row = 2, col = 2;
    Object[][] objArray = new Object[row][col];
     for(int i = 0 ; i < row; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                 objArray[i][j] = arrayList.get(k);
                 k++;
                 if(k > arrayList.size()) {
                     break;
                 }
         }
     }
     for(int i = 0 ; i < row; i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

             System.out.println("Row no "+i+" col no "+j+" "+objArray[i][j] );
         }
  }
 }
```

Comment: So Above is a way to convert your ArrayList<string> to a 2D Array. Above i have converted ArrayList<string> into 2D Object. For converting it into 2D string or 2D array just replace above code with String[][] for 2D string and Array[][] for 2D Array.

Comment: You should write the explanation in the answer itself instead of writing it in the comments.