# How to create 2D array of Object from a List?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jtable

I would like to convert `ArrayList` into 2D array of `Objects`. List is something like

```
[[AD,ADCB, N], [AFC, Fund, Y], [IO, dfdfdfd, N]]
```

I would like to convert this List into array of objects and I would like to modify Y, N field into Boolean Values someting like

```
Object[] rowdata = {
    {AD, ADCB, Boolean.FALSE}, 
    {AFC, Fund, Boolean.TRUE}, 
    {IO, dffdfdf, Boolean.FALSE}}
```

after that I can stuff into `JTable` model and those `boolean` values will be visible as `JCheckboxes`.

What should be the best way to convert this list into 2D array of objects so that I can pass into `JTable` `TableModel`?

Comment: "[[AD,ADCB, N], [AFC, Fund, Y], [IO, dfdfdfd, N]]" - is it a String?

Comment: This might help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146488/converting-an-arraylist-into-a-2d-array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146488/converting-an-arraylist-into-a-2d-array

Comment: Be sure to mark the correct answer for future readers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you show that there are three members of each object that you want to store. So, if N is the number of items in your arraylist, you need a multidimensional array of N * 3. ie:

```
Object[][] table = new Object[list.size()][3];
```

Then you're going to use a for loop, to cycle through each object in the list:

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
{
     Object currentObject = list.get(x);
     table[x][0] = currentObject.getValue();
     // Load the first value.
     ...
     table[x][2] = currentObject.getYorN().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")? true:false;
     // Embed a selection statement to decide if to store true or false.
}
```