# How to convert a ArrayList into 2D array in Java 7

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-7

I am trying to convert a Integer list in a 2D array in java 7. I first converted a String list to Integer and then Integer list to 2D array. Then I will do more operations as required.
What I tired is

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1110", "1010", "1011", "1110");
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        intList.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
    }
    //the problem is from here
    int[][] array = new int[intList.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            array[i][j] = intList.get(j + (list.size() * i));
        }
    }
```

I tried solving my issue looking at this [Converting an ArrayList into a 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146488/converting-an-arraylist-into-a-2d-array) and this [Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays) but majority of the answers are given in java 8 which I don't want! i know its a basic problem but i am stuck! Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance!

The resulting 2D array should be like

`1110`

`1010`

`1011`

`1110`

Comment: What is the condition behind 1D to 2D ? Give an example in you post

Comment: [edit] your question and post the resulting 2D array that you want to get from the example list in your question.

Comment: Ok I edited it! Please have a look

Comment: The example you give at the end doesn't look like a 2D array.

Comment: Every string represent 1D  array ? means `{1,1,1,0}{1,0,1,0}` ...?

Comment: It will certainly look like a 2d array if you write them in separate lines!

Comment: Yes @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks you got my point!  Strings which are present in my list represents 1d array!

Comment: @CodeDexter `1110` seems like a single integer and you are doing operation like `Integer.valueOf(s)` for `1110` that also makes confusion. You can update your question with an example for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.charAt()` to get the character of the position in every string.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1110", "1010", "1011", "1110");
int[][] array = new int[list.size()][list.get(0).length()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).length(); j++) {
        array[i][j] = list.get(i).charAt(j)-'0';
    }
}
```